# dnsmasq - detect mx-host changes without service restart

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, dnsmasq

I have a mailserver on ubuntu with postfix and dnsmasq. It has a bunch of `mx-host` records on the `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` config file. I need to dynamically update (add/remove) these mx-host entries (and the change propagated) without having to restart dnsmasq service itself.

The issue I have with `restart` is it can take some time for the operation to complete and there is downtime as a result of it (emails get deferred and sometimes sent to mx address that results in a loop). I could not find any way to achieve this yet. No hint on this in [manpage](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) too. I am fine with `reload` of the service if that is possible.

```
#/etc/dnsmasq.conf
mx-host=domain1.com,domain1-hostname.com,10
mx-host=domain2.com,domain2-hostname.com,10
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !